# Wordpress custom title from custom php file

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, filter, title

I'm trying to change Wordpress page title from a custom php page loaded via php everywhere plugin. The page is loaded via include and it is working fine. It gets data from an API and displays the results. Changing the title from within the custom file is really a challenge though.

As far i can see i have to use a filter. I managed to change the title with static text via a filter pre_get_document_title in either functions.php or a plugin that i created. Unfortunately though i can not pass the title from the custom php file to the function called. I'm trying to use a global variable, but as far a i can see the variable change in the custom php file is called after the filter is applied, therefore the variable is empty. I also tried to find an action to call the filter e.g. before the page is sent to the browser, but couldn't get the value from the php file. How can i get the title from the custom php to the filter's callback function ? Any thoughts or hints are highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Plugin's code

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'testfunc' );
function testfunc($title) {
   global $globalflightstatustitle;
   return $globalflightstatustitle;
}
```

Custom php file code

```
global $globalflightstatustitle;
$globalflightstatustitle = "hello aaaaaaa";
```

also tried

```
$GLOBALS['globalflightstatustitle'] = "hello aaaaaaa";
```

alternative method in plugin

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'changetitle' );
function changetitle()
{
    add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'testfunc' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case someone else faces the same issue. My solution was to move the API request to the plugin, that is called prior to the custom php code. The title and meta is changed in testfunc and the API result is stored in a public variable accessed later on in the custom page. Case solved.